# Parse user group information from Azure token?

Tags: angularjs, azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, adal

I am working with **Angular JS** and now I need to authenticate my application with **Azure AD SSO** .

Currently, I implemented same with **adal-angular**. Now apart  of my requirement I need to parse  user group information form the **JWT** token which I got after successful authentication(I am passing this token to my backend service and there I need to parse it)

I came to know that azure adal-angular implementation is not sending group information, reference available [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2b49109b-b98a-4b54-b644-43d623a7d36a/azure-ad-jwt-token-is-missing-group-information?forum=WindowsAzureAD).

- 1-Is there any way to get user group information from current implementation?
- 2-Is there any library available rather than adal-angular?
- 3-Can I call graph API to get group information using JWT token which provided by azure adal-angular ?

Any suggestion please and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set groupMembershipClaims to "SecurityGroup" or "All" in your app's manifest in AAD , then you can receive the users' group memberships in the id token (which gives you the user's name etc) . Please refer to [document](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/) for more details.

Please refer to code sample :https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp . To get group claims , update `UserData.html` to get  ids of groups :

```
<p ng-repeat="value in userInfo.profile.groups">{{value}}</p>
```

Another way is getting group memberships from [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_getmembergroups) :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberGroups
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 33

{
  "securityEnabledOnly": true
}
```

For how to call an Azure AD protected Web API(microsoft graph in your scenario) in an AngularJS Single Page App . Please refer to code sample :https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi